# getting a "this program may not be used for excuting instructions" error when making a simple spl transfer

Tags: python, solana, solana-transaction-instruction, solana-py

i'm trying to send an spl-token transaction but it's not working, it's a transacion on the devnet with a token that i newly created, my code is

```
    from spl.token.instructions import transfer, TransferParams
    from spl.token.client import Client 
    from solana.publickey import PublicKey
    from solana.transaction import Transaction
    from solana.keypair import Keypair

    address = "address sending from"
    my_token = "3hALJzSz2bx8gxgrHg7EQQtdiHxG7d7LNswxVMXrUApw" #token addredd on devnet
    private_key= "64 bit key"



    def send_payouts_spl(dest,amount):
        source = address
        transfer_params= TransferParams(
        amount=amount,
        dest=PublicKey(dest),
        owner=PublicKey(source),
        program_id=PublicKey(my_token),
        source=PublicKey(source)
        )
        txn = Transaction()
        txn.add(transfer(transfer_params))
        solana_client = Client("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
        owner = Keypair.from_secret_key(private_key)
        tx_id  = solana_client.send_transaction(txn, owner)
        return tx_id
```

and also the error that i'm getting

> solana.rpc.core.RPCException: {'code': -32002, 'message': 'Transaction simulation failed: This program may not be used for executing instructions', 'data': {'accounts': None, 'err': 'InvalidProgramForExecution', 'logs': [], 'unitsConsumed': 0}}

also if it helps, my devnet token address and my devnet address are

3hALJzSz2bx8gxgrHg7EQQtdiHxG7d7LNswxVMXrUApw, EckcvMCmpkKwF4hDhWxq8cm4qy8JBkb2vBVQDu4WvxmM    respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solana, there's typically just one token program that is shared for all token types (mints).

When you provide the `program_id`, you shouldn't provide the address for your mint, but rather the id for the SPL Token Program, which is `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`.  Also, the `owner` should be the key that owns the token account.

So instead, try:

```
    owner = Keypair.from_secret_key(private_key)
    transfer_params= TransferParams(
        amount=amount,
        dest=PublicKey(dest),
        owner=PublicKey(owner.public_key),
        program_id=PublicKey('TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'),
        source=PublicKey(source)
    )
```

Comment: thank you! one more thing, any idea how to fund wallet when i'm sending an spl token to it? becuz i'm having an error if it doesn't have a token account already

Comment: That's correct, you have to create the recipient's token account if they don't already have one, using something like `create_associated_token_account` https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/251403dbf5f528ce3870f9cb19dfaedcdee3ffb1/src/spl/token/async_client.py#L180